# Добавить иконку в кнопку

Tags: android

Есть класс, который позволяет свайпом управлять элементами списка. При свайпе отображаются три кнопки. Пример класса взят отсюда https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44965278/recyclerview-itemtouchhelper-buttons-on-swipe.

Есть возможность вывести иконку для каждой кнопки, но не могу сообразить как. Как это делается?

В данном классе есть подкласс UnderlayButton, в котором задается `int imageResId`. Т.е. можно задать любую иконку для кнопки.

Как отрисовать саму иконку далее в классе `UnderlayButton` в методе onDraw. Переменная `imageResId` сейчас не используется нигде.

P.S. и еще сразу вопрос. Все три кнопки отображаются впритык в самому элементу когда свайп делаю. Как сделать небольшой отступ этих кнопок от самого элемента?

```
public abstract class SwipeHelper extends ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback {

    public static final int BUTTON_WIDTH = 150;
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private List<UnderlayButton> buttons;
    private GestureDetector gestureDetector;
    private int swipedPos = -1;
    private float swipeThreshold = 0.5f;
    private Map<Integer, List<UnderlayButton>> buttonsBuffer;
    private Queue<Integer> recoverQueue;

    private GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener gestureListener = new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener(){
        @Override
        public boolean onSingleTapConfirmed(MotionEvent e) {
            for (UnderlayButton button : buttons){
                if(button.onClick(e.getX(), e.getY()))
                    break;
            }

            return true;
        }
    };

    private View.OnTouchListener onTouchListener = new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent e) {
            if (swipedPos < 0) return false;
            Point point = new Point((int) e.getRawX(), (int) e.getRawY());

            RecyclerView.ViewHolder swipedViewHolder = recyclerView.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(swipedPos);
            View swipedItem = swipedViewHolder.itemView;
            Rect rect = new Rect();
            swipedItem.getGlobalVisibleRect(rect);

            if (e.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN || e.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP ||e.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
                if (rect.top < point.y && rect.bottom > point.y)
                    gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(e);
                else {
                    recoverQueue.add(swipedPos);
                    swipedPos = -1;
                    recoverSwipedItem();
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    };

    public SwipeHelper(Context context, RecyclerView recyclerView) {
        super(0, ItemTouchHelper.LEFT);
        this.recyclerView = recyclerView;
        this.buttons = new ArrayList<>();
        this.gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(context, gestureListener);
        this.recyclerView.setOnTouchListener(onTouchListener);
        buttonsBuffer = new HashMap<>();
        recoverQueue = new LinkedList<Integer>(){
            @Override
            public boolean add(Integer o) {
                if (contains(o))
                    return false;
                else
                    return super.add(o);
            }
        };

        attachSwipe();
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onMove(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, RecyclerView.ViewHolder target) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onSwiped(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int direction) {
        int pos = viewHolder.getAdapterPosition();

        if (swipedPos != pos)
            recoverQueue.add(swipedPos);

        swipedPos = pos;

        if (buttonsBuffer.containsKey(swipedPos))
            buttons = buttonsBuffer.get(swipedPos);
        else
            buttons.clear();

        buttonsBuffer.clear();
        swipeThreshold = 0.5f * buttons.size() * BUTTON_WIDTH;
        recoverSwipedItem();
    }

    @Override
    public float getSwipeThreshold(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder) {
        return swipeThreshold;
    }

    @Override
    public float getSwipeEscapeVelocity(float defaultValue) {
        return 0.1f * defaultValue;
    }

    @Override
    public float getSwipeVelocityThreshold(float defaultValue) {
        return 5.0f * defaultValue;
    }

    @Override
    public void onChildDraw(Canvas c, RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, float dX, float dY, int actionState, boolean isCurrentlyActive) {
        int pos = viewHolder.getAdapterPosition();
        float translationX = dX;
        View itemView = viewHolder.itemView;

        if (pos < 0){
            swipedPos = pos;
            return;
        }

        if(actionState == ItemTouchHelper.ACTION_STATE_SWIPE){
            if(dX < 0) {
                List<UnderlayButton> buffer = new ArrayList<>();

                if (!buttonsBuffer.containsKey(pos)){
                    instantiateUnderlayButton(viewHolder, buffer);
                    buttonsBuffer.put(pos, buffer);
                }
                else {
                    buffer = buttonsBuffer.get(pos);
                }

                translationX = dX * buffer.size() * BUTTON_WIDTH / itemView.getWidth();
                drawButtons(c, itemView, buffer, pos, translationX);
            }
        }

        super.onChildDraw(c, recyclerView, viewHolder, translationX, dY, actionState, isCurrentlyActive);
    }

    private synchronized void recoverSwipedItem(){
        while (!recoverQueue.isEmpty()){
            int pos = recoverQueue.poll();
            if (pos > -1) {
                recyclerView.getAdapter().notifyItemChanged(pos);
            }
        }
    }

    private void drawButtons(Canvas c, View itemView, List<UnderlayButton> buffer, int pos, float dX){
        float right = itemView.getRight();
        float dButtonWidth = (-1) * dX / buffer.size();

        for (UnderlayButton button : buffer) {
            float left = right - dButtonWidth;
            button.onDraw(
                    c,
                    new RectF(
                            left,
                            itemView.getTop(),
                            right,
                            itemView.getBottom()
                    ),
                    pos
            );

            right = left;
        }
    }

    public void attachSwipe(){
        ItemTouchHelper itemTouchHelper = new ItemTouchHelper(this);
        itemTouchHelper.attachToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
    }

    public abstract void instantiateUnderlayButton(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, List<UnderlayButton> underlayButtons);

    public static class UnderlayButton {
        private String text;
        private int imageResId;
        private int color;
        private int pos;
        private RectF clickRegion;
        private UnderlayButtonClickListener clickListener;

        public UnderlayButton(String text, int imageResId, int color, UnderlayButtonClickListener clickListener) {
            this.text = text;
            this.imageResId = imageResId;
            this.color = color;
            this.clickListener = clickListener;
        }

        public boolean onClick(float x, float y){
            if (clickRegion != null && clickRegion.contains(x, y)){
                clickListener.onClick(pos);
                return true;
            }

            return false;
        }

        public void onDraw(Canvas c, RectF rect, int pos) {
            Paint p = new Paint();

            // Draw background
            p.setColor(color);
            c.drawRect(rect, p);

            // Draw Text
            p.setColor(Color.WHITE);
            //p.setTextSize(LayoutHelper.getPx(MyApplication.getAppContext(), 12));

            Rect r = new Rect();
            float cHeight = rect.height();
            float cWidth = rect.width();
            p.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.LEFT);
            p.getTextBounds(text, 0, text.length(), r);
            float x = cWidth / 2f - r.width() / 2f - r.left;
            float y = cHeight / 2f + r.height() / 2f - r.bottom;
            c.drawText(text, rect.left + x, rect.top + y, p);
            clickRegion = rect;
            this.pos = pos;
        }
    }

    public interface UnderlayButtonClickListener {
        void onClick(int pos);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Пусть у вас есть некий адаптер и RecyclerView, назовем их:

NotificationsAdapter adapter;

RecyclerView recyclerView;

В самом адаптере вы указываете элементы какие там должны быть, картинки текстовые поля  и т.д. Для примера, их 6.

Пример простейшей реализации свайпа:

```
ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback touchHelper = new ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback(0, ItemTouchHelper.LEFT) {
    @Override
    public boolean onMove(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, RecyclerView.ViewHolder target) {
    return true;
    }
    @Override
    public void onSwiped(final RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int direction) {
         // что-то делаем
    }

    @Override
    public void onChildDraw(Canvas c, RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, float dX, float dY, int actionState, boolean isCurrentlyActive) {
    // сдвиг влево - удаляем из from RV
    View f1 = ((NotificationsAdapter.MyViewHolder) viewHolder).itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    View f2 = ((NotificationsAdapter.MyViewHolder) viewHolder).itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView58);
    View b1 = ((NotificationsAdapter.MyViewHolder) viewHolder).itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView56);
    View b2 = ((NotificationsAdapter.MyViewHolder) viewHolder).itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView24);
    View b3 = ((NotificationsAdapter.MyViewHolder) viewHolder).itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView54);
    View b4 = ((NotificationsAdapter.MyViewHolder) viewHolder).itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView55);
    if (actionState == ItemTouchHelper.ACTION_STATE_SWIPE && isCurrentlyActive) {
        helper.enableViews(f1,f2);
        helper.hideViews(b1,b2,b3,b4);
    }else{
        helper.enableViews(b1,b2,b3,b4);
        helper.hideViews(f1,f2);
    }
    super.onChildDraw(c, recyclerView, viewHolder, dX, dY, actionState, isCurrentlyActive);
}
```

};
// подключаем свайпер к recycler view

```
new ItemTouchHelper(touchHelper).attachToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
```

Comment: За ответ спасибо! Но свайп уже реализован. Хотелось бы просто место текста выводить иконки.

Comment: для этого создайте адаптер с нужными элементами, а и показывайте нужные картинки в разные моменты свайпа.

Comment: Мой вопрос в том как вывести иконку в кнопке, а не как создать адаптер или реализовать свайп(. Это все уже реализовано.